# How can a style applied to a given node be inherited by all descendants of that node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, graphs

I'm using the `graphs` TikZ library to draw directed acyclic graphs. When I apply a particular style to a given node, I would like that style to be inherited by all descendants of the node in question.

To fix ideas, say I've defined a node style called `alert` that modifies the default node style. When I apply that `alert` style to a node locally, I would like all descendants of that node to inherit the style in question, without having to apply that style to all its descendants manually.

Here is an illustrative example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={draw=black},
  alert/.style={draw=red},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph{
  A -> {
    B,
    C[alert] -> D -> { E, F},
  },
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

At the moment, `alert` is only applied to node `C`.
However, by applying the `alert` style to node `C`, I would like all descendants of `C` (i.e. nodes `D`, `E`, and `F`) to inherit that style, without having to type

```
\graph{
  A -> {
    B,
    C[alert] -> D[alert] -> { E[alert], F[alert]},
  },
};
```

Is there a way of doing that?

---

**Edit**: [Harish Kumar's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199937/21891) can make my life much easier, but is not exactly what I want. Here is a more complex example illustrating what's missing:

```
\graph{
  A -> { B, C[alert] }  -> D -> { E -> F, G -> H }
};
```

[image]

Here, I'd like nodes `D` to `H` to inherit the `alert` style applied to their ancestor, node `C`.
I could follow Harish's advice and write

```
\graph{
  A -> { B, C[alert] }  -> {[nodes=alert] D -> { E -> F, G -> H }}
};
```

[image]

but that would still force me to apply `alert` *twice* in the graph. I would like a particular style applied to one node to be inherited by all nodes further down the chain

- without having to  that style anywhere else, and
- no matter how the graph is specified.

Is that even possible?

Comment: You can use a scope.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you mean a `scope` environment?

Comment: There are limitations as `{B, C}` fall within a group. Whatever you specify for node `C`, it is difficult to carry over to `D` `E` etc.

Comment: @HarishKumar I'm wondering whether what I'm asking for is even possible...

Comment: @Jubobs Well, you know the rules ;-) May be some wizard will appear with some black magic! Let us see.

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes, let's wait. If no TikZ wizard conjures up some kind of spell, I'll give you the checkmark back `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
{[nodes=alert]C -> D -> { E, F},
  }
```

code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={draw=black},
  alert/.style={draw=red},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph{
  A -> {
    B,
    {[nodes=alert]C -> D -> { E, F},
  }},
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I missed that in the manual. For information, it's documented in *19.3.2 Syntax of Group Specifications*.

Comment: That's actually not exactly what I want, but that will do for now.

Comment: @jubobs did I leave anything out?

Comment: I'll edit my question to add a more involved example.